# how I fix too many re-renders in React?

Tags: reactjs

I save json Objects in local Storage, and If I have a Local Storage, so I say I want the local storage value put in my state in React. But it not working why? Its a simple code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Create = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  const isLocal = localStorage.getItem('posts');
  if(!isLocal) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();
    setTimeout(() => {
      axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', { signal: abortCont.signal})
      .then(result => {
        setPost(result.data);
        localStorage.setItem('posts', result.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        if(e.name == 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Aborted Succesfully');
        }
      })
    }, 1000);

    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, []);

  } else {
    setPost(isLocal);
  }

  return (
    <>
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <ul>
      {isLocal}
    </ul>
    </>
  )
};

export default Create;
```

Comment: why you need setTimeOut ?

Comment: `useEffect` should not be called conditionally. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html. Your `else` is most likely the cause. It will infinitely update `post` until `isLocal` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code :
first to avoid multiple re render issue you can move your condition block in the `useEffect` and add `isLocal` in it's dependencies:

```
const isLocal = localStorage.getItem("posts");

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();
    if (!isLocal) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
          signal: abortCont.signal
        })
          .then((result) => {
            setPost(result.data);
            localStorage.setItem("posts",JSON.stringify(result.data));
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            if (e.name == "AbortError") {
              console.log("Aborted Succesfully");
            }
          });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
     
      setPost(JSON.parse(isLocal));
      
    }
    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, [isLocal]);
```

As you can see we fix too the issue with isLocal .
IsLocal in local storage is not type of object but type of string so you need to parse it an stringify to have an object array.
With the return function (it's up to you to choose how and what you want to display):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Create = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  const isLocal = localStorage.getItem("posts");

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();
    if (!isLocal) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
          signal: abortCont.signal
        })
          .then((result) => {
            setPost(result.data);
            localStorage.setItem("posts",JSON.stringify(result.data));
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            if (e.name == "AbortError") {
              console.log("Aborted Succesfully");
            }
          });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
     
      setPost(JSON.parse(isLocal));
      
    }
    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, [isLocal]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      <hr/>
      {post && post.map(p=>  <div key={p.id}> <h3>{p.title}</h3>
      <p>
        {p.body}
      </p>
      <hr/>
      </div>)
     }
      
    </>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

**UPDATE**
You can declare `isLocal` directly in the `useEffect` hook (before your condition of course ;)) and remove it from it's dependencies and leave an empty array.
[image: Edit mystifying-satoshi-yksxx]